# TestFlight SDK troubles

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, testflight

testflight sdk is working in my simulator only. I can't see number of sessions from my devices. Have you any ideas? Can you send tutorial to me?

Comment: you might want to add ***testflight*** to your tag.

Answer (score 2):

TestFlight has pretty active support people. you should start discussion there on your particular problem.

[Start Discussion TestFlight](http://support.testflightapp.com/discussion/new)